# Is possible to user char[] instead of Strings in a Servlet for password storing?

Tags: java, security, servlets, passwords

I read several articles and posts about security regarding (note
[Comparing input password to stored hashed password in a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804627/comparing-input-password-to-stored-hashed-password-in-a-web-app) or [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Since to retrieve a parameter value from request uses request.getParameter("passwordFieldName") which returns a String, is there any option to retrieve a parameter from request as a char[]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I extract a password from a HttpServletRequest header without generating a String object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016250/in-java-how-do-i-extract-a-password-from-a-httpservletrequest-header-without-ge)

Answer (score 0):

*Unfortunately I know of no way.*

The request parameters are already loaded, hopefully internally as reused byte[] or char[]. But then?

So maybe one should reimplement a bit of HTTP server? Not me.

You could on the client side split the password in more than one variable and encrypt them. Whether that is better?

If you do not trust your server platform, better use **OpenID** or an other delegated authentication.

Answer (score -2):

You can just use the `String`'s method `toCharArray` to convert it into a `char[]`.

```
String str = request.getParameter("passwordFieldName");
char[] pwArr = str.toCharArray();
```

See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) for more info.

Comment: You can also use `getBytes(String charset)` to get the string as a `byte[]`.

Comment: str.toCharArray() returns a NEWLY allocated character array (see javadoc) , therefore the String password str will be present anywhere in the system, in any thread dump/heap analyzer, until garbage collection, and  that's what I trying to avoid

Comment: I believe the password will be present in all cases, since it will be in memory within the request on the server. No matter what you do, the string password will be present in memory somewhere.

Comment: fwiw Restlet seems to do it better according to tihs page: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.  Note how the Basic Auth code (there's a link to Github there for the full code) gets the secret as a char[] and writes it to the headers as such, without an interim String being created anywhere. I'm using Jersey, not Restlet but found this code while looking for answers